# Implementing twitter sign in - app asks too much permissions with default settings

Tags: authentication, twitter, oauth

I am implementing a sign in with twitter for a web app using OAuth and Node.JS backend.
And I want to ask as less permissions as possible.
Like all I need is user id, screen_name, name profile picture, email.
That's all. I do not need to read user tweets or send tweets on user behalf.
I do not need read user settings, etc. Even current status aka latest tweet unnecessary.

With current implementation the Twitter's authorize screen shows this `scary` list of permissions:

```
This application will be able to:

See Tweets from your timeline (including protected Tweets) as well as your Lists and collections.
See your Twitter profile information and account settings.
See accounts you follow, mute, and block.
See your email address.
```

While I need just something like this:

```
This application will be able to:

See your Twitter profile information.
See your email address.
```

Is there a way to configure Twitter app or the OAuth 1.0a server-side flow to reduce scopes of requested access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible in the current Twitter implementation.